# Compile typescript lib to es2015 and CommonJs modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a shared React component library compiled with typescript. At the moment I'm compiling the library with CommonJs modules but I would like to have also the ES2015 modules available in order to get [Webpack tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) available in the consumer project.

The library folder structure looks like this:

[image: folder structure]

The `index.ts` file is where I have the public API. An example would be:

```
// Components
export { default as AlertBox } from './components/AlertBox/AlertBox';
export { default as Button } from './components/Button/Button';
```

And I have this typescript configuration (`tsconfig.json`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["public/*", "src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.*"]
}
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
tsc && tsc -m es6 --outDir lib-esm
```

But this compiles all the project to es6 modules, so I will end up with all the code duplicated.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have only 2 different `index.ts` (public API). One with es6 modules (`index.es.ts`) and the other one with CommonJs (`index.ts`). Somehow like [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) is doing.

[image: material-ui folder structure]

Is there a way get those files only with typescript?

Comment: Did you find out how to di this?

Comment: Hey @distante I finally migrated to [RollupJs](https://rollupjs.org/) for bundling my library. The process was very straightforward :)

Comment: Hi @gerard-brull! I am (right now this second!) testing RollupJs, but I do not like that it does prints any error from the typescript compiler and I can not find a way to make it generate the typescript definitions...

Comment: I'm using [react-styleguist](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/) for the components so I'm forced to used webpack for dev development. I use rollup for bundling the library for production and then I'm generating the typescript definitions with `tsc --emitDeclarationOnly` command. Not the best setup I guess but it works at least :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydDUm1yPZs0&lc=UgybSfrM0NdkNRwJaAt4AaABAg.9Hdzf8Xhu6c9HlM4nMxHFq - check out this video.. And the comments for Webpack5 if you go that route.